# Ordered field and Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Hello I need help for a task I am trying to solve. I was able to solve most of the tasks,and would like to know if my solutions are correct. There is one task, that I don't know how to solve unfortunately.

The set L={(a,b): a,b ∈ ℝ} forms a field with the operations
(a,b)+(c,d):=(a+c,b+d); (a,b)*(c,d):=(ac-bd,ad+bc)

a)Determine the identity elements of addition and multiplication of L and calculate $(0,1)^2$.

Since the identity element of addition is (-x) for x --> x+(-x)=0, the identity element of addition for L is: (-(a+c),-(b+d)).Right?

The identity element of multiplication is: ($(ac-bd)^-1$,$(ad+bd)^-1$)

To calculate $(0,1)^2$ we multiplicate (0,1)*(0,1) and get (-1,0) with a=0,b=1,c=0,d=1.

b)We already proofed that for an ordered field K, --> $k^2$>0 for k∈K without{0}. Conclude that L is not an ordered field.

Well since $(0,1)$^2=(-1,0)<(0,0) which proves that L is not an ordered field.

c)Show that for all (a,b) ∈ L there exisit a sequence {(an,bn)}n∈ℕ with an,bn ∈ ℚ  sucht that $\sqrt{(an-a)^2+(bn-b)^2}$ -->0 for n-->$\infty$

Well this is the task that I am not able to solve. I have no idea how to show that.

Comment: You are confusing identity elements and inverses.  In the reals, $0$ is the additive identity and $-x$ is the additive inverse of $x$.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my fault. But what are the additive/multiplicative identitys here? (0,0) and (1,1)?

Comment: You should be able to find them from the definition.  You need $(x,y)+e=(x,y)$ for example.  Express $e$ as two components and see where it takes you.  Similarly for multiplication.  For b, you have to show that there is no order possible on this field.  You don't know whether $(-1,0)$ is greater than or less than $(0,0)$.  Show that either one leads to a contradiction.  For c, you just work componentwise.  Have you shown the rationals are dense in the reals?

Comment: Well then the additive inverse is (0,0) and the multiplicative inverse is (1,0). Correct? For b I don't really get it. How do I prove that there is no order possible for an ordered pair. For c, no I did not do that. But i don't understand the task at all. I can't imagine what this sequence should look like and what the Limit of the root has to do with the sequence.

Comment: Those "inverses" are the correct identities.  For b, however you compare  $(0,1)$ and $ (0,0)$  square it to show $(-1,0) \gt (0,0)$.  Then $(1,0) \lt (0,0)$ and reach a contradiction.  For c you should have a proof that you can approach any real by a sequence of rationals.  You can follow that proof here in each axis.

Comment: Do you know that you're constructing $\mathbb C$, the set of complex numbers?

Comment: @RossMillikan It doesn't matter if (0,1) is greater or bigger than (0,0). You are right, we don't know that. What we now is L is an ordered fit, if (0,1)^2>(0,0). We proofed that if k>0 or k<0, then k^2>0. Since (0,1) and (0,0) are different, (0,1) is either bigger or smaller, which leads us to the result that (-1,0)>0. So how am I gonna show that this result is a contradiction. Imhave to proof that (-1,0)<0....but how

Comment: @mr_e_man arenyou talking about c)?